# Bringing cheese to Canada from France

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, france, food-and-drink

I can't find any clear website on what cheeses I can bring to Canada from France.

I would like to bring:

- mozzarella (the fresh one that is packaged with some liquid),
- soft cheeses: Brie, Roblochon and Camembert,
- hard cheeses: Emmental, Beaufort and Comté,
- fresh cheeses: Little Goat Cheese "crottin".

[Canadian Food Inspection Agency](http://www.inspection.gc.ca/food/information-for-consumers/travellers/what-can-i-bring-into-canada-/eng/1389648337546/1389648516990) says the limit is 20 kg, but it's not clear which ones I am allowed.

[Agence canadienne d'inspection des aliments](http://airs-sari.inspection.gc.ca/AIRS_External/francais/decisions-fra.aspx) (in French) also has an inventory of all cheeses allowed or not, but it's not always clear.

Comment: Have you done research into which cheeses will be safe to leave unrefrigerated for that long? This article implies soft cheeses should definitely be ruled out. https://www.thestreet.com/slideshow/12798317/5/7-foods-can-survive-outside-fridge.html

Answer (score 4):

Just don't forget any layover (US, UK ...) when you fly from France to Canada. Their customs apply.

On your [second link in French](http://airs-sari.inspection.gc.ca/AIRS_External/francais/decisions-fra.aspx), I found Brie and Camembert in the search bar.

Forget about :

- mozzarella di bufala, it must be fresh to consume within the day.
- crottin , Beaufort, Reblochon, Comté ( not found on http://airs-sari.inspection.gc.ca/AIRS_External/francais/decisions-fra.aspx)

But isn't there any Brie and Camembert in Canada ?

I'm impressed by the limit of 20kg of dairy products

> Dairy products (e.g.: cheese, milk, yogurt, butter)
>
> - up to **20 kilograms** per person

Comment: Regarding you position on crottin, etc., there is an "Other cheeses" category on the link you provided (SH code 040620357599)